# Update WCF service reference

Tags: wcf, reference, biztalk

In BizTalk 2006 R2, is there some way to regenerate the reference to a WCF service that has been created using the "Add Generated Items / Consume WCF Service" option?

I tried just re-running the wizard, but it creates new ODX, BindingInfo, etc. files, and breaks the solution, so that's not the way  :-(

Searched the web, but not found any references to how to update the references, just plenty on creating from scratch

Comment: Does it matter that those are new files? Since the files only hold type information, can't you replace the files in your current project with the newly generated ones? (i know its not a 'refresh' as you'd like to see, but i think it should work)

Comment: FWIW I've put a checklist of todos / gotchas during regeneration in the second part of the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734813/biztalk-and-the-best-way-to-call-web-service/13743458#13743458)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Marvin, delete the old files and generate new ones.

If you keep the old ones before you regenerate you will of course have other names on the newly created, like **yourname1.odx** if you choose the same name as before (**yourname**), and breaking the solution that way, since the type name will be different.