# Update WCF service reference in Biztalk 2010

Tags: wcf, reference, biztalk

I have consumed a WCF service in a biztalk solution by "Add generated items". Then I build up a quiet lenghty orchestration. Now I have to update the service (Add another method). How can I update the reference of that service in the project. Is there any direct way or I have to delete all files and do all things from point zero? (I am using biztalk server 2010.)

Comment: No, AFAIK the easiest is still to delete all the generated items and regenerate them again. Main issue is to remember to keep the same NameSpace name and to re-promote / distinguish any fields in the generated schemas. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734813/biztalk-and-the-best-way-to-call-web-service/13743458#13743458) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781790/update-wcf-service-reference)

Comment: Are you using [multi-part message types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163423.aspx#S1) in your orchestration? That'll help ease the pain.

Comment: yes I am using multi-part message types which service has offered by default(Request and Response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method to update service reference which is consumed through "Add generated Items" wizard. One possibility is to Make a separate folder in project and add reference again in that folder.